# My error handler stopped working when i moved it into a cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I moved the kick function and the kick error handler from the main function to a cog but now it throws an error

**Main File**

```
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('token')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Initialised as {client.user}")

# loading the cogs
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'): 
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

**Cog**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Moderation is online')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reson=None):
        if member is None: 
            await ctx.reply("Usage: .kick @user reason", mention_author=False)
        else:
            await member.kick(reason=reson)
            await ctx.reply("done",mention_author=False)

    # This stopped working
    #------------------------
    @kick.error()
    async def kick_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
            await ctx.reply("Member not found", mention_author=False)
     #------------------------
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Moderation(client))
```

**Error message**: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Moderation.kick_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given